Is there an event corresponding to the start of a new process that I can subscribe to without administrative privileges?
The following code starts conhost.exe which, in turn, starts a new instance of pwsh.exe.  Process start events are filtered until the pwsh.exe process whose parent is that instance of conhost.exe is found:
$sourceId = [guid]::NewGuid().guid

Register-CimIndicationEvent                   `
    -ClassName        Win32_ProcessStartTrace `
    -SourceIdentifier $sourceId

$descendantProcessName = 'pwsh.exe'

$parentProcess =
    Start-Process                            `
        -FilePath     conhost.exe            `
        -ArgumentList $descendantProcessName `
        -PassThru

while ($true) {
    foreach ($event in (Wait-Event                  `
                        -SourceIdentifier $sourceId )) {
        $event | Remove-Event
        $newProcess = $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent

        if ($descendantProcessName -ne $newProcess.ProcessName) {
            continue
        }
        if ($parentProcess.Id -ne $newProcess.ParentProcessId) {
            continue
        }
        Get-Process -Id $newProcess.ProcessID
        Get-EventSubscriber                 `
                -SourceIdentifier $sourceId |
            Unregister-Event
        Remove-Event                    `
            -SourceIdentifier $sourceId `
            -ErrorAction      SilentlyContinue
        return
    }
}

The following is typical output:
PS C:\>.\test.ps1

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
     61    35.63      88.23       0.05    9584   3 pwsh

That process corresponds to the (first) new instance of pwsh descended from conhost.exe.
I have found this technique of waiting on new process events to find new descendants to be robust even when working with installers whose tree of descendant processes can be remarkably elaborate.  The polling alternative is vulnerable to missing short-lived intermediate processes altogether.  That makes it much more difficult (or perhaps impossible) to establish whether a particular new process descended from the one you started.  Such short-lived intermediate processes often seem to live just long enough to launch some descendants before completing.
Unfortunately, though, the call to Register-CimIndicationEvent fails when run without administrative privileges on Windows:
Register-CimIndicationEvent: C:\test.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  Register-CimIndicationEvent `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Access denied

Is there an event corresponding to the start of a new process that I can subscribe to without administrative privileges?

What is the use-case for this? What will be done when a new process is found?

@lit In the case of invoking an installer, the metadata of each process event is used to build a current tree of descendant processes such that all of those processes are awaited for completion prior to proceeding with further installation tasks.  I use the same technique for other use cases, but the installer scenario has been the most troublesome.

How was the value of $sourceId determined? Are you saying that some installers create processes that do not end before the initial process completes?

@lit "How was the value of $sourceId determined?" Aahh...I should have shown that.
I updated the question.  $sourceId is just GUID to correlate event registration and listening.

@lit "Are you saying that some installers create processes that do not end before the initial process completes?" Yup.  In particular some larger system/driver installers that are actually a number of smaller installers that the vendor carefully crafts to install disparate subcomponents in just the right order with just the right arguments.  Intel and nVidia graphics drivers distributed by Dell are some examples that come to mind.

I eventually came across this answer which states:

Unlike the extrinsic event Win32_ProcessStartTrace that you are currently using, the __InstanceCreationEvent and __InstanceDeletionEvent WMI intrinsic events do not require administrator rights.

Indeed, replacing the registration and process extraction with
Register-CimIndicationEvent                            `
    -Query "SELECT TargetInstance
            FROM   __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 0.1
            WHERE  TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'" `
    -SourceIdentifier $sourceId

and
$newProcessHandle =
    $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Handle
$newProcess =
    Get-CimInstance `
        -Query "SELECT *
                FROM   Win32_Process
                WHERE  Handle = $newProcessHandle"

yields the same result as the original code without administrator privileges.
Missed events, processor usage, and polling interval
WITHIN 0.1 in the registration query refers to a polling interval of 0.1 seconds.  The documentation for the WITHIN clause contains the following statements:

...This interval is the maximum amount of time that can pass before notification of an event must be delivered. A consumer uses a polling interval in a WITHIN clause when the consumer requires notification of changes to a class, and an event provider is unavailable. The consumer registers for an intrinsic event and includes the polling interval.
...
...the interval should represent a number of seconds rather than an extremely small value such as 0.001, because specifying a value that is too small can cause WMI to reject the statement as not valid—due to the resource-intensive nature of polling. Because most event consumers do not require immediate notification, it is recommended that they use an interval that is greater than 5 minutes.

This related answer states the following:

All intrinsic events (like __InstanceCreationEvent) in WMI makes use of polling to detect changes - there is always a chance that a particularly short event will be missed. By decreasing the polling interval you will definitely improve the detection rate however there's absolutely no guarantees.

These two perspectives seem to be in conflict.  If a polling interval of 5 minutes were to be of any use then whatever machinery prepares the events must be queuing those events during that 5 minute period.  That model is at odds with the assertion that short events will be missed.
I prepared a test that subscribes to __InstanceCreationEvent, starts a flood of processes, and counts the number of unique processes reported to check for lost events.  The test is performed over a range of polling intervals.  The test also measures processor usage of the WmiPrvSE processes during each trial.
Test results from my computer are below.  On this Dell Precision 5470 no events are missed at polling intervals of 100ms and below.  There is clearly subsantial WmiPrvSE processor activity for the duration of each flood of processes starting.  As much can be seen in Task Manager, and is confirmed by the test result table.  However, the WmiPrvSE processor usage is stable across two orders of magnitude of polling interval.  In other words, processor usage doesn't seem to increase as polling interval is decreased (at least in this range).  Reliability, on the other hand, does improve as polling interval is decreased.  In this usage, at least, I do not see a benefit to a longer polling interval.
For reference, the same test can be run with -privileges admin which subscribes to Win32_ProcessStartTrace instead.  That test yields remarkably similar processor usage which suggests that the two methods are likely using similar machinery.
Whether the processor usage is acceptable will depend on the application, I suppose.  But these tests suggest that if processor usage is acceptable at any polling interval, then a short polling interval probably should be selected for reliability.
polling_interval_ms trial expected actual lost result cpu_time_s test_duration_s apparent_processor_load timed_out
------------------- ----- -------- ------ ---- ------ ---------- --------------- ----------------------- ---------
                  1     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.31            0.27 24%                         False
                  1     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.20 31%                         False
                  1     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.23            0.20 30%                         False
                  1     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.23            0.20 31%                         False
                  1     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.21            0.19 33%                         False
                  1     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.20 31%                         False
                  1     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.20            0.18 34%                         False
                  1     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.21            0.19 32%                         False
                  1     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.25 25%                         False
                  1    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.21 30%                         False
                  3     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.21            0.19 32%                         False
                  3     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.20 31%                         False
                  3     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.17            0.14 41%                         False
                  3     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.20 31%                         False
                  3     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.19            0.17 34%                         False
                  3     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.19 32%                         False
                  3     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.19            0.18 33%                         False
                  3     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.20            0.18 33%                         False
                  3     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.23 27%                         False
                  3    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.19            0.17 34%                         False
                  5     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.18            0.16 37%                         False
                  5     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.18            0.15 39%                         False
                  5     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.23            0.22 29%                         False
                  5     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.26 25%                         False
                  5     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.22 28%                         False
                  5     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.26            0.23 28%                         False
                  5     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.21 29%                         False
                  5     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.28            0.25 25%                         False
                  5     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.27            0.24 27%                         False
                  5    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.19            0.17 36%                         False
                 10     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.19            0.17 36%                         False
                 10     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.28            0.24 26%                         False
                 10     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.26 25%                         False
                 10     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.20            0.19 32%                         False
                 10     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.23            0.21 30%                         False
                 10     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.21            0.18 33%                         False
                 10     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.27 24%                         False
                 10     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.22 28%                         False
                 10     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.26            0.23 27%                         False
                 10    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.25            0.22 28%                         False
                 30     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.20            0.17 35%                         False
                 30     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.28            0.24 26%                         False
                 30     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.25 25%                         False
                 30     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.31            0.27 24%                         False
                 30     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.25 26%                         False
                 30     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.25            0.22 29%                         False
                 30     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.21 30%                         False
                 30     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.30            0.27 24%                         False
                 30     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.21            0.17 35%                         False
                 30    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.19 32%                         False
                 50     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.28            0.25 25%                         False
                 50     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.32            0.26 25%                         False
                 50     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.19            0.16 37%                         False
                 50     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.33            0.29 23%                         False
                 50     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.30            0.26 25%                         False
                 50     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.32            0.29 23%                         False
                 50     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.30            0.26 25%                         False
                 50     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.23            0.21 29%                         False
                 50     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.25            0.22 29%                         False
                 50    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.30            0.26 25%                         False
                100     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.22 28%                         False
                100     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.30            0.26 25%                         False
                100     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.32            0.27 24%                         False
                100     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.22            0.19 33%                         False
                100     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.25 25%                         False
                100     6       10     10    0 ✅            1.43            0.38 19%                         False
                100     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.24            0.21 30%                         False
                100     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.29            0.24 26%                         False
                100     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.28            0.25 26%                         False
                100    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.26            0.22 29%                         False
                300     1       10     10    0 ✅            1.50            0.46 16%                         False
                300     2       10     10    0 ✅            1.57            0.52 15%                         False
                300     3       10     10    0 ✅            1.53            0.49 16%                         False
                300     4       10     10    0 ✅            1.57            0.52 15%                         False
                300     5       10     10    0 ✅            1.56            0.51 15%                         False
                300     6       10      9    1 ❌            6.11            5.09 6%                           True
                300     7       10     10    0 ✅            1.57            0.51 15%                         False
                300     8       10     10    0 ✅            1.52            0.48 16%                         False
                300     9       10     10    0 ✅            1.51            0.47 16%                         False
                300    10       10     10    0 ✅            1.52            0.48 16%                         False
                500     1       10      8    2 ❌            4.69            3.64 6%                           True
                500     2       10      9    1 ❌            5.82            4.77 6%                           True
                500     3       10      8    2 ❌            4.65            3.62 6%                           True
                500     4       10      8    2 ❌            5.29            4.26 6%                           True
                500     5       10      8    2 ❌            4.73            3.69 6%                           True
                500     6       10      9    1 ❌            6.48            5.44 6%                           True
                500     7       10      9    1 ❌            4.64            3.60 6%                           True
                500     8       10      9    1 ❌            5.84            4.80 6%                           True
                500     9       10      9    1 ❌            5.78            4.75 6%                           True
                500    10       10      9    1 ❌            4.62            3.59 6%                           True


@mklement0 Interesting.  Do you have a repro demonstrating missing a process?  I did not succeed at achieving that.  I can imagine a design where polling of queue indeed takes place, but that queue is guaranteed to contain all the events.

I may have jumped to conclusions: I missed that  it is events that are being polled, not processes. So, assuming that there is indeed a queue that prevents events from slipping through the cracks (do you know its length / how it is managed?), only half of my (since deleted) comment applies: polling in short intervals can increase the CPU load noticeably.

Re event queuing: here's a clue (for a definitive answer, more research is needed): There is an __EventQueueOverflowEvent WMI class that "reports when an event is dropped as a result of delivery queue overflow" and "queue size [...] defaults to 10 MB for all queues combined." Even though there's no subscriber (consumer) in your query, per your feedback it sounds like the events are queued nonetheless.

Thank you for the event queue reference.  I guess a robust implementation should do some error checking on __EventQueueOverflowEvent.

I managed to provoke missing events in some circumstances.  I added the test results to my answer.  Reliability seems to hinge on the time between registration and the start of the first process.  After imagining how this subsystem might be designed, that doesn't really surprise me.  I measured the reliability threshold to be 3x polling interval.  Perhaps you could see if you get the same result.  My test code is linked in the answer.

Great sleuthing, thanks. When I run your test with a shorter-lived process (cmd.exe /c ver), I see that that 1, 3, 5 polling-interval tests consistently fail, and occasionally even the 0.3 interval - irrespective of the advance registration ratio.

My guess is: while events are queued in principle, the associated process terminating results in the queued event's instant removal, which may happen between polling intervals.

Your guess seems to fit.  Another hypothesis is that a queue overflows above that interval.  I updated the tests for shorter intervals.  I'm not persuaded that there is, in fact, a problem of increasing processor usage at lower polling intervals.  The test results don't support that relationship.  (Although processor usage is significant at any interval.)  With cmd.exe /c ver I see no missed events at 100ms and below.
